# Stuck using string.length() function?

Tags: android, crash

I just began in Java and Android. This website already helped me a lot.

Here I'm stuck with something very easy. In other language I never had problem but there..

If I try the following, i have no error on eclipse but once running in the emulator, the software crash at the "if" line.

```
String message = mOutEditText.getText().toString();

        if (message.length() > 4) {
```

If I use **if (8 > 4) {** then I have no problem.

I also tried `if (message.toString.length() > 4) {` without any success.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did u debug your program and checked?

Comment: whats the logcat say?  is it a null pointer exception?

Comment: May it happen, that your `message` variable is `null`? What kind of error do you get?

Comment: Share your full code and LogCat, it's probably an easy fix. Are you initializing the mOutEditText correctly as well?

Comment: @Harinder If you try to call any method on null object you will get NPE.

Comment: What Vivart said. It's 99% a NPE.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say without knowing the error but just about the only thing that could possibly go wrong with that line is a `NullPointerException` i.e. when you have this problem, it is because:

```
String message = mOutEditText.getText().toString();
```

is effectively resolving to:

```
String message = null;
```

Most likely this is because your `EditText` does not have any text in it (from the name of your variable I'm guessing you are using an `EditText`).

You can account for this case by checking that `message` is not `null`. Here is one way of doing it:

```
if (message != null && message.length() > 4) {
```

Comment: Yes Gary Buyn that's correct. Actually I'm used that this function return 0 and not crash in other language. I'm used of C / VB / PHP and Java is really different, I think I will have some tough work ! Thanks :)

Comment: @Lemon Yeah in Java `null != 0` unlike C.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, you initialize message as a static string like "Stack overflow" and try

```
message.length();
```

if it works, then there is no problem with toString() function.

Best of luck..!!

Answer (score 0):

In String There are two way of getting the length of String:-this is working properly

String message=""; 
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ s.length();}